# XSLTProcessor in PHP always removes white space

Tags: php, xslt, whitespace

I'm trying to use XSLTProcessor to combine some XML and a XSLT stylesheet to combine to a html file.
However it always results with outputting the html in 1 line.

So for example my XSLT:

```
<p>
    <strong>my sheet</strong>
    this is <strong>my</strong> <em>style</em>
</p>
```

Turns into:

```
<p><strong>my sheet</strong>this is <strong>my</strong><em>style</em></p>
```

I am using:

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
```

But I would like to preserve my html as it is.
Anyone has any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preserve-space deals with the processing of elements and their contents from the data file, and does not affect how the script is parsed. The short answer is that you can't, and shouldn't.

If you have significant whitespace (for example two spans which need a space in between to prevent the words running together) then you add it in with `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>`. If you don't have significant whitespace (for example, between `<h1>..</h1> space <p>...`), then you shouldn't try to add it in.

XML is there to precisely, reliably transfer a document tree from one program to another, and being pretty is in no way part of its job. XSLT won't add in whitespace, because it doesn't know where it is safe to do so, and it won't take it away, because it doesn't know where that is useful. Remember XSLT know nothing about HTML; it's markup language independent. To do what you want, XSLT would need to know that it can put space around block elements (`h1`, `p`, etc) but not around spans, otherwise you might get floating punctuation:

```
my cunning paragraph with
<span>text</span>
, and more
```

The above is clearly not acceptable output. Because it doesn't know what elements are safe and what aren't, XSLT does the obviously correct opinion and doesn't risk malprocessing your data for sake of some pretty-printing.

XML is not designed to be written by hand, nor read as raw data. Don't try it. Open the XML output in Firefox, and it can do the formatting for you, and if you want it took pretty, do that in another application.

For completeness, there is in fact one safe way of doing pretty printing without affecting spacing:

```
<root
  ><h1>The correct way of handling pretty-printing with XML</h1
  ><p
    >A test paragraph with a <span
    >span</span
    >, which won't break</p
  ></root
>
```

Finally, kill ISO-8859-1. It must die. Try to avoid `h1` inside `p`.

Comment: What's wrong with ISO-8859-1? (assuming that you know that you will be using European characters)

Comment: so there is no way to get this working:
`<p><xsl:value-of select="firstname" /> <xsl:value-of select="lastname" /></p>` ?

Comment: You never know you'll only be using characters from a few European languages. All it takes someone to copy and paste a curly quote from Office. Most European languages aren't properly covered; even English isn't completely. A user posts his comment about his Œdipus complex? Oops, not in Latin-1. It's silly to use a deficient encoding which XML processors are not required to support, instead of an easier, better supported one required by the standard. Latin-1 documents should be a legacy problem, not a growing problem.

Comment: There is, as I said: put in an `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>`. That's significant whitespace, and is significant enough to need you to use an XSLT instruction to add it in. It will still run things onto one line, but that's fine. The space will be preserved if you tell XSLT you want it there by instructing it to output that text.

Comment: (Also, apologies for rant, but this one comes up often and rubs me the wrong way a bit.)

Comment: Well I used the search but I thought no one had found a solid solution. So I guess it's just not possible then, however for people who want to use xsl:text:

`$this->template = preg_replace('/([^<!]*>)\s([^>!]*<)/', '$1<xsl:text> </xsl:text>$2', $this->template);`

This isn't very performance optimized, however for me that is not an issue.

Comment: What! No! That's horrible! Never use regular expressions like that; they're so brittle and unsafe. For the situations like in your second comment, between first name and last name, you put the `xsl:text` in the XSL file, rather than adding it in the PHP.

If you have some desperate and strange need to pretty-print your XML, the 'correct' solution is to write out the resultant tree using a little XMLWriter class of your own on the output tree, rather than using the standard `saveXML` method. The writer class would use the method described above, with whitespace safely inside the tags.

Comment: Re: ISO-8859-1: you can always use numeric character entities though.